# JMenuItem to load a file

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to load a specific file (C://myfile.txt) by clicking on a menue item in the file menu bar, I need help to complete the action part of the code

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open",
            KeyEvent.VK_O);
openMenuItem .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Load the file
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Um... what help do you need? I assume you've read the file I/O tutorials, and so that begs the question -- just where are you stuck? And what exactly do you mean by *"load"* the file?

Comment: For my money, I'd use a Scanner to read in a text file, and you can find the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html). But again if you want more specific help, you'll have to ask a much more specific question.

Comment: thanks for answering, I actually need to open a file say (myfile.txt) by clicking on the Open menue item. I don't want to have a pop up window for selecting the file then opening it, I just need to have the file opened when clicking on the open thing. Thanks

Comment: OK, I assume you wish to open the file to read it, correct? So what have you tried so far? And again, where are you stuck? Have you read the link on Scanning I've provided? Please don't make us have to pull teeth to get this thing clarified.

Comment: I have added action listener to the open menu item and I think I need to implement actionListener method for setting the event. I am stuck in making the event    openMenuItem .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //How to open the file?
        }
    });

Comment: Are you perhaps looking to just have the text file open up in a text editor? In that case something like this `Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file);` is probably what you want.

Comment: @chands: you may be right. But til the original poster clarifies things, who knows?

Comment: You never said that you wanted it to be opened in another app. What a frustrating thread. Please next time, tell the details from the start.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am quite new in java and swing, I think my question was not perfectly understood in the first place. the problem is been solved though, thanks to all :)

Answer (score 2):

All I can tell you is very general recommendations and they include:

- Create a File object with your file's path and name (assuming you already know this -- you haven't told us yet).
- Create a new Scanner object with the File object.
- Iterate through the Scanner line by line as per the tutorial that I linked to above using a while loop (example below)
- Then close the Scanner object.
- If the file is more than a very short one, you'll want to read it in a background thread such as can be provided by a SwingWorker object.

Example of use of Scanner:

```
// try and catch blocks will be needed to handle exceptions.
File myFile = new File(myFilePathAndName);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
while (scanner.hasNextLine) {
   String line = scanner.nextLine();
   // do with line as you see fit
}
scanner.close();
```

Again, if you want more specific help, please provide more of the details of your problem and your question. Again please read the tutorials and API's as they are very helpful.